# How to download freebase dump through the terminal?

Tags: graph, download, rdf, freebase, triplestore

I could download the freebase dump by pressing the big green button on this page: https://developers.google.com/freebase/data

but i need to get it onto the server in which i only have remote terminal access, does anyone know how to `wget` or somehow download the freebase dump through the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the HTML for that page, you'll see that the URL is http://download.freebaseapps.com but you should a) be sure that you follow redirects so that you get to the actual file and b) be prepared to change your download code because freebaseapps.com is going away in the near future.

Edit:

A couple more URLs in case this does change.  The first is the current redirect target for the above:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/freebase-public/rdf/freebase-rdf-2014-02-09-00-00.gz

This is the bucket that all the files are stored in:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/freebase-public/

A red herring to watch for is this one:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/freebase-public/rdf/freebase-rdf-latest.gz

Looking at its metadata, it doesn't actually appear to be the latest, despite it's name.  Ignore it.